# How to real-time update comments using Parse?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm posting/saving comments using Parse but it doesn't really update what user's currently looking at.

For example, on Instagram while reading a picture's comments, if any new comment's posted by someone, you see it right away. How does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. 
You'd have to use something like PubNub which is another service for your app besides Parse.

Found a clear and detailed answer here -
http://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-use-Parse-com-for-realtime-chat-like-Socket-io